# Change Default page to login

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We would like to change the default landing page from home to login page.

We tried from CMS - we changed the starting-page of site to login page, made homepage as not-default and this brought the login page. However, it's not refreshing or redirecting to HomePage after successful login.

Also we have to redirect the user back to login page when they log-out.

Has anyone implemented this or any suggestions how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: Is your homepage accessible only for authenticated users? If yes you can make use of protected routes (see `ProtectedRoutesService`) - setting homepage as default will redirect to login anyways and after authenticating user will be redirected back to the homepage.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I actually added AuthGuard to a component and this redirected to login page and on successful login, we are redirected to home page. Yes, ours is a B2B site and users have to login before the login page.

Answer (score 0):

In spartacus-configuration-module.ts file inside imports array add the below code

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
routing: {
    protected: true,
}})
```

This will ensure all the pages is only after login. Documentation - https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/early-login/